# Difference in directory size when copying using SCP

Tags: centos, files, filesystems, nfs, scp

I am copying a number of directories from centos 6 to centos 7 the file system in the source system is NFS while in destination is NFS4, I noticed that the sizes of directories are smaller in the destination ? Is this normal and why did this happen ?

Answer (score 2):

NFS is not really a filesystem type: it is a network protocol for sharing files and directories, but the NFS client plugs into (the rest of) the kernel like a filesystem. Essentially, the NFS client pretends to be a filesystem driver, while the actual filesystem is on the NFS server, using whatever filesystem type is supported by the server's kernel.

RHEL/CentOS 6 and 7 have different default filesystem types: while RHEL/CentOS 6 systems are likely to use `ext4` filesystems, RHEL/CentOS 7 systems will most likely use `xfs`.

Different filesystem types use different metadata structures, and so the size of the directory may be different even though it contains exactly the same files.

Also, in some filesystems (like `ext4`), the size of a directory (as displayed by `ls -ld`) may reflect not only how many files the directory currently has, but also how many files it used to contain in the past. If you write a large number of files into a single directory, the filesystem automatically allocates more space for the directory metadata - but when you delete files, those allocations are not always immediately freed, on the assumption that you might soon write more files to this directory again. This is partly a performance optimization, partly to minimize directory metadata fragmentation.

In extreme cases, you might want to explicitly shrink the directories to match the number of files they currently have, e.g. by running an `e2fsck -D` "optimize directories" operation on `ext4` filesystems (requires unmounting), or just by moving all the contents you wish to keep to a new directory, deleting the old directory, and renaming the new directory the same as the old. The latter approach can be handy if e.g. a malfunctioning program has spewed tens of thousands of files into a directory that normally contains just a handful of files.

Comment: Thanks @telcoM , I just need a way to verify the integrity of folders copied using SCP the folder is 2 TB , how can I achieve this for a file I use md5sum to verify integrity but for directory containing thousand of files how this can be done ?

Comment: You might want to make a separate question post for that.